# I need to read an .mdb on node.js but on linux

Tags: node.js, linux, ms-access

I need to read an Access file (.mbd) on node.js, but I can't because I was trying to do it with node-adodb, but it is unsupported platform. Can you suggest me how to do it without node-adodb?

Thank you!

Comment: [mdbtools?](https://github.com/mdbtools/mdbtools)